# apply method doesnt work on canvas context lineTo()

Tags: javascript, canvas, apply

I cannot find the reason why this doesn't work:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo.apply(this, [100, 100]);
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: What do you expect `this` to be here?

Comment: What did you expect to happen? What really happened? Are you getting any error messages? What have you tried thus far to solve the problem?

Comment: @xdazz - I expected drawing a line.

Comment: @PPvG - It didnt do anything, no errors, no effects, I didnt know what to try. But finally solved, see the last post at the bottom, thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, `this` is either `window`... which really doesn't know what to do with `.lineTo`, or `this` is whatever object owns the function that this code is wrapped in.

If this code is not wrapped in a function (or even if it is, if that function is anything other than the property of an object, `this` === `window`).

eg:

```
MyObj.myFunc = function () {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
    //  ..........etc
    ctx.lineTo.apply(this, [100,100]);
};
```

That code would call `.lineTo` using `MyObj` as `this`.
If `MyObj` didn't know what to do with that information, or `.lineTo` couldn't find the properties it needed attached to `MyObj`, then it will fail.

In almost all other cases of reading from `this`, instead of writing to it, `this` refers to `window`.

Another common pitfall: functions inside of functions.

```
MyObj = {
    name : "Bob",
    sayName : function () {
        console.log(this.name); // works -- "this"===MyObj
        var say_it_again = function () {
            console.log(this.name + ", for the second time");
        };
        say_it_again();
        // second function doesn't work -- "this"===window
};
```

in order to scope `this` properly in this case, save it as a variable in the first function, and reference it in the second.

```
MyObj = {
    name : "Bob",
    sayName : function () {
        var person = this; // now the reference to "this" is kept in "person"
        console.log(this.name); // works -- "this"===MyObj
        var say_it_again = function () {
            console.log(person.name + ", for the second time");
        };
        say_it_again();
        // works -- "person" refers to the saved variable in the first function
        // that variable happens to hold a reference to "this" from the first function
        // which happens to be MyObj
};
```

Answer (score 3):

OK, I make it work after your answer, thanks. I thought that THIS pointed to ctx variable.

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo.apply(ctx, [100, 100]);
ctx.stroke();
```

Thanks, bye ;)

Answer (score 0):

`lineTo` depends on the `this` object being a context

Normally you call it as `ctx.lineTo(...)`, implicitly setting `this=ctx`

However when you use `.apply`, you have the option to override `this`

If you say `....lineTo.apply(this, ...)` you are setting `this` to be whatever it happens to be in scope (usually the `window` object, or something else if you use dot-notation).

Therefore do `.....lineTo.apply(ctx, ...)`